# How to avoid appending incremental number to filename

Tags: 7, files

I don't want Drupal to add incremental numbers to my file names to make them unique. I want to always have files stored with the same name they had when I uploaded them.

If the file with given name already exist, "Replace already existing file?" prompt should appear instead of default behaviour.

Comment: Hello and welcome. It seems English is not your first language. It is not my first language, either ;) So to be sure: You want to have "Replace file?" dialog instead of default behaviour: number appended to filename to make it unique? And you want to always have files stored with the same name they had when you uploaded them?

Comment: Yes you are absolutely clear with the requirement Mołot

Comment: I edited it for you, hope it will attract more attention (and answers) now. As we can see with NWOM's answer, your question was easy to misunderstood, but I think we have it figured out. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The [Upload File Replace](https://drupal.org/project/upload_replace) module should do the trick:

> Module Page Description
>
> This is a small utility module that automatically stops Drupal from
>   renaming new files upload via filefield CCK. When 2 files with the
>   same name exist, the older files will be renamed.

Edit: Sorry, I missed the part where you are expecting a prompt. According to the comment below, it is not possible.

Comment: There are two issues with it: 1) it does not provide a dialog, it overwrites silently, and 2) 7.x-1.0-beta1 worked very, very unstable for me (messing managed files table et cetera). Can't tell about dev from 2013-Oct-19 - maybe it's better now?

Comment: @NWOM Files are still getting renamed after using this utility,I think i am missing something please suggest?